# How to automatically update XML comments?

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, comments

I am looking for a way to automatically add / delete XML-formatted comments in VB.net sourcecode. Let me elaborate more on this with a short example:

Initial iteration with auto commenting could look like this:

```vb
''' <summary>Summary for AnyFunction</summary>
''' <param name="Var1"></param>
''' <param name="Var2"></param>
''' <remarks>Remarks...</remarks>
Sub AnyFunction(Var1 As Variable1, Var2 As Variable2)
    [...]
End Sub
```

Now within the 2nd iteration AnyFunction gets extended by another variable...

```vb
''' <summary>Summary for AnyFunction</summary>
''' <param name="Var1"></param>
''' <param name="Var2"></param>
''' <remarks>Remarks...</remarks>
Sub AnyFunction(Var1 As Variable1, Var2 As Variable2, Var3 As Variable3)
    [...]
End Sub
```

...or reduced by deleting an already declared variable

```vb
''' <summary>Summary for AnyFunction</summary>
''' <param name="Var1"></param>
''' <param name="Var2"></param>
''' <remarks>Remarks...</remarks>
Sub AnyFunction(Var1 As Variable1)
    [...]
End Sub
```

Since comments from first iteration do not get updated automatically, manual adjustments become necessary which is super annoying when dealing with large numbers of classes and functions.

Any suggestions/ideas for Visual Studio Add-Ins or options/settings to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot for your time and effort in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by _"iterations"_? Are you creating this dynamically or are you just referring to when you add/remove parameters?